# How to install utils.lib in anaconda to run a jupyter notebook for python?

Tags: python, anaconda

In a jupyter notebook running on anaconda there is a line "import utils.lib as lib". When I run it, I get the error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.lib'".

I tried to search for the utils.lib on Internet so that I can install it. But I could not find it. Please let me know how to install it. Thank you -- Manoranjan Dash

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide the code context for the import line. You don't have to always provide the complete context; however, you didn't provide anything and that is why the Bot tried to encourage you to improve things. 'Additional context' would also be important to supply in your post such as the source of the notebook or any related blog post, etc..

---

The only place I see that import come up on the internet besides your post is [here](https://ruslanmv.com/blog/Speech-Recognition-with-RNN-Neural-Networks). The code there shows how to get that and install it under 'Downloading the utils and installing':

```py
LIB_DIRECTORY_PATH = DIR+'/utils'
# Check if utils directory already exist, otherwise download, and install
import os
import shutil
if not os.path.isdir(LIB_DIRECTORY_PATH):
    if not os.path.isdir(DIR+'/utils'):
        os.mkdir(DIR+'/utils')
    print('Downloading utils')
    user = "ruslanmv"
    repo = "Speech-Recognition-with-RNN-Neural-Networks"
    src_dir = "utils"
    pyfile = "lib.py"
    url = f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{user}/{repo}/master/{src_dir}/{pyfile}"
    !wget --no-cache --backups=1 {url}
    print("Installing library...")
    shutil.move(DIR+'/lib.py', DIR +'/utils/lib.py')
    print("Done.")
```

Source of that above code: https://ruslanmv.com/blog/Speech-Recognition-with-RNN-Neural-Networks

---

Code that the code block retrieves and places in the correct location is found [at this repo](https://github.com/ruslanmv/Speech-Recognition-with-RNN-Neural-Networks/). It isn't something you install. You need to place it alongside the notebok. (Ideally it is set up so you just download or clone the repository, it looks like to me.) The [utils directory and it's content](https://github.com/ruslanmv/Speech-Recognition-with-RNN-Neural-Networks/tree/master/utils) is what you need to get or make/copy and place along with your notebook.

Direct link to raw code it gets:

```bash
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ruslanmv/Speech-Recognition-with-RNN-Neural-Networks/master/utils/lib.py
```

Comment: Highly appreciate your detailed comments. Yes, you have found the exact same github code that I am trying to run where I encountered this "import utils.lib"... Following your suggestion, I re-run the code (adjusting the directory path from linux to windows, etc.), and it could overcome the import utils.lib problem and tried to run thru the lib.py inside utils directory. Now I have a new problem at "import cv2" inside lib.py. My attempts have not succeeded yet in installing cv2 in windows 10 anaconda. Thank you again!

Comment: Hopefully you'll find there's some other posts around on installing opencv2 into Windows using Anaconda. You may want to start with trying to run `%conda install -c conda-forge opencv` (based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv)) inside the notebook where you are working. Be sure to try restarting the kernel after running that.